# looping through an array with an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I am currently working with the following array,

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [candidate_id] => 41
                    [show_on_site] => urban talent
                    [first_name] => Barney
                    [surname] => Harwood
                    [gender] => male
                    [talent] => presenter
                    [skill] => 
                    [DOB] => 1983-11-30
                    [Location] => London
                    [contact_telephone] => 01234 567890
                    [contact_email] => barney@bluepeter.co.uk
                    [height] => 5' 1"
                    [eyes] => Brown
                    [hair_colour] => brown
                    [hair_length] => medium
                    [accents] => Native Northern, others include - Yorkshire, Liverpool, Manchester, Birmingham, Cockney, RP, Welsh, Scottish, German, American
                    [training] => n/a
                    [unions] => Member of the British Academy of Composers & Songwriters
Equity & MU Member
                    [visible] => yes
                    [availability] => yes
                    [availability_number] => 9999
                    [availability_order] => 0
                    [availability_comments] => BARNEY IS THE LATEST BLUE PETER PRESENTER AND CAN BE SEEN ON AIR MONDAYS & TUESDAYS AT 4.30PM ON BBC
                    [spotlight_url] => 
                    [youtube_showreel] => 
                    [date_created] => 2011-11-02 10:44:37
                    [created_by] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [candidate_id] => 42
                    [show_on_site] => urban talent
                    [first_name] => Simon
                    [surname] => Ainley
                    [gender] => male
                    [talent] => actor
                    [skill] => 
                    [DOB] => 1987-06-12
                    [Location] => Huddersfield
                    [contact_telephone] => 01484 532751
                    [contact_email] => simonainley@the-factory.co.uk
                    [height] => 5' 1"
                    [eyes] => blue
                    [hair_colour] => brown
                    [hair_length] => short
                    [accents] => Accents
                    [training] => Training
                    [unions] => Union Membership
                    [visible] => yes
                    [availability] => yes
                    [availability_number] => 9999
                    [availability_order] => 0
                    [availability_comments] => Availability Comments
                    [spotlight_url] => http://www.google.com
                    [youtube_showreel] => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sP4NMoJcFd4
                    [date_created] => 2011-11-08 11:28:12
                    [created_by] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

as you can see it is an array within an array type situation, I am trying to loop through it to pull out the `first_name` + `surname` of each entry, however I get the following error when I try to do it,

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: firstname

Filename: admin/candidate_list.php

Line Number: 5
```

I looping through it like this at the moment,

```
<?php foreach ($candidates as $k => $v) : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>candidates/card/id/<?php echo $v['id']; ?>"><?php echo $v[0]['first_name']. " ".$v[0]['surname']; ?></a></li>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What you need is nested loops. a loop inside your loop

Comment: Are you sure your code is up to date? According to the error you're trying to access `$v['firstname']` and not `$v['first_name']`.

Comment: @sico87: It's hard to tell from the code you've provided. Can you show us how you define `$candidates`?

Answer (score 0):

What does this give you?

```
<?php foreach ($candidates as $k => $v) print_r($v); ?>
```

I don't know how $v['id'] would be defined either given that array, so there's something else you're leaving out...

And you're using site_url()... Do I smell CodeIgniter? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your array is too deep for that loop. I am assuming that `$candidates` is the name of the whole big array? You don't need each candidate in their own array, try getting your results in an array that has one less level and that `foreach` will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?
    for($i=0; $i=50; $i++){
    foreach ($candidates[$i] as $v){
    ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>candidates/card/id/<?php echo $v[0]['candidate_id']; ?>"><?php echo $v[0]['first_name']. " ".$v[0]['surname']; ?></a></li>
    <?
    }
    }
?>
```